# Unable to run hubot locally

Tags: hubot

I keep getting this error. How should I solve it?

> npm WARN hubot-slack@4.5.4 requires a peer of hubot@^2.0.0 but none is
>   installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
>
> audited 339 packages in 2.26s found 2 vulnerabilities (1 low, 1 high) 
>   run `npm audit fix` to fix them, or `npm audit` for details ./hubot:
>   8: exec: node_modules/.bin/hubot: not found

Answer (score 0):

This can be a dependency issue. Do check the dependencies.
Also run the commands **npm audit** and **npm audit fix** to get deep into the issue.

Answer (score 0):

You should run hubot not from the `bin` directory but from the parent directory as:

```
bin/hubot
```

Reference: https://github.com/hubotio/hubot/issues/1061#issuecomment-179422364